# Can not see System.out result in intellij run window

Tags: intellij-idea

I used Intellij well. Start from yesterday, I can not see System.out.println result in run/debug window. Even exception error message.
For example, System.out.println("This is test"). After run it, it shows nothing in the run window. Only display "Process finished with exit code..".
If I compile with jar file, I can see the print. If I use System.setout to a file, I can see them.
But can not see in Intellij console. Anything wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Check [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) for errors. See if you can reproduce it in a new project. Try reinstalling IDE. Could be some permissions issue or an antivirus blocking process execution (AppSense Application Manager is known to cause such issues).

Comment: Thank you. I checked the idea.log with cleaned it before. Nothing special.  I tried to use Android studio and run a test case to use System.out.println. Looks good.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out` output should be written to the Run or the Debug tool window depending on whether you launch the run/debug configuration as Run or Debug. Make sure your launch configurations are correct.

Comment: I make sure the launch configuration is correct. It worked before.